# How to create an arraylist from a file where the input for the program is IntegerType?

Tags: java, arraylist

Forgive me if this may seem elementary/answered but I am not understanding how to apply it to my program. I'm trying to create a program that accepts an array of either integers or strings from a text file which will then be sorted by other classes with the `isBetterThan()` method in the sort classes.

How can I accept input from a text file line by line to create an array of IntegerType or StringType? (Integer/String and File will be user input.)

As it sits, I'm getting an error which is either "no suitable method" for the array class or "incompatible types". Thanks.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class Insert
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        //Variables
        String fileName;
        IntegerType line;
        ArrayList<IntegerType> aList = new ArrayList<IntegerType>();

        //Ask for which file
        Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.print ("Enter the pathname of the input file: ");
        fileName = scan.nextLine();

        Scanner s = new Scanner(new File(fileName));

        //--------------------My problem
        while (s.hasNext()){
            aList.add(s.next());
        }
        s.close();

    }
}

class IntegerType implements AnyType {

   private int number;

   public IntegerType() {
       number = 0;
   }

   public IntegerType(int i) { 
       number = i;
   }

   public boolean isBetterThan(AnyType datum) {
    return (this.number > ((IntegerType)datum).number);
   }

   public int toInteger() {
    return number;
   }
}

class StringType implements AnyType {

   private String word;

   public StringType(){
       word = "";
   }

   public StringType(String s){
        word = s;
   }

   public boolean isBetterThan(AnyType datum) {
    return (this.word.compareTo(((StringType)datum).word) > 0);
   }

   public String toString() {
    return word;
   }
}

interface AnyType {
   public boolean isBetterThan(AnyType datum);
}
```

Comment: can you tell us which line you get the error?

Comment: @KickButtowski It is marked with `//--------------------My problem` in the main method.

Comment: You are trying to add result of `Scanner#next` which is String to list `ArrayList<IntegerType> aList` which as you declared should store instances of `IntegerType` type, not Strings. What are you trying to achieve here? What data you expect from `next` method? If you expect `next` to return only numbers then maybe consider something like `aList.add(new IntegerType(s.nextInt()));`

Comment: can you show us your file content?

Comment: It compiled with `aList.add(new IntegerType(s.nextInt()));` with no errors, but my output when I printed `aLink.get(1)` was "IntegerType@4e181a7a"

|The text File is 2000 random numbers on separate lines as follows:

70
35
81
8
96
64
46
57
99
19

Comment: `IntegerType@4e181a7a` is default result for `toString` method inherited from Object class (Type@hexHashcode). You need to override `toString` method to return String representing stored value if you want to print it. Anyway from your code I don't see why you need separate classes. It looks like you could use  `String` or `Integer` since (they implement `Comparable` so they have `compareTo` method, you can use it instead of `isBetterThan`).

Comment: @Pshemo I did not see the wrapper class IntegerType. I updated my answer so plz lemme know if you like it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your code, your file contains integers and you try to read each token one by one and add it to your ArrayList which carry the type Integer.

Lets take a look at the part you try to read your file one token at the time

```
   while (s.hasNext()){
        aList.add(s.next());
    }
```

Let's break it down

what does `s.hasNext()` means?

```
public boolean hasNext()
```

> Returns true if this scanner has another token in its input. This
>   method may block while waiting for input to scan. The scanner does not
>   advance past any input. Specified by: hasNext in interface
>   **Iterator which is type String**

what does `s.next()` means?

`public String next()`  <--- **as you see it return type String**

**Finds and returns the next complete token from this scanner. A complete token is preceded and followed by input that matches the delimiter pattern. This method may block while waiting for input to scan, even if a previous invocation of hasNext() returned true.**

I believe the issue arias when you try to add String to the ArrayList which is in type Integer

```
 listInt.add(in.next());
```

**Good news** is you can parse `in.next()` which is in `String` type to type `Integer` by using

```
Integer.parseInt(whatever you want to conver to type Integer);
```

your while loop will be changed to

```
       while (in.hasNext()) {
            String token = in.next();
            listInt.add(Integer.parseInt(token));

        }
```

For validation goal to see if your input is String or Integer

```
try {
  Integer.parseInt(text); 
  return true; 
 } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
 return false;
 }
```

try this sample for distinguishing between String and Integer type

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "1 a b 2";
        String[] sp = s.split(" ");

        for (int i = 0; i < sp.length; i++) {
             if(stringOrInteger(sp[i]))
                 System.out.println(sp[i] + " is type Integer");
             else
                 System.out.println(sp[i] + " is type String");
        } 

    }

    private static boolean stringOrInteger(String s) {
        try {
            Integer.parseInt(s);
            return true;
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

output:

```
1 is type Integer
a is type String
b is type String
2 is type Integer
```

**I did not see you have a wrapper class name IntegerType:**

you can use hasNextInt to read each token from your file since they are in type int

```
public boolean hasNextInt()
```

> Returns true if the next token in this scanner's input can be
>   interpreted as an int value in the default radix using the nextInt()
>   method. The scanner does not advance past any input.

and since in your wrapper class you have constructor which is

```
  IntegerType it = new IntegerType(variable type int goes here);
```

how to read variable type int?

use `nextInt()` which

> means Scans the next token of the input as an int.

so your while loop become :

```
       List<IntegerType> listInt = new ArrayList<>();
        while (in.hasNextInt()) {
                IntegerType it = new IntegerType(in.nextInt());
                listInt.add(it);
        }
```

and for printing your variable you have to use toInteger() from your wrapper class

```
      for (int i = 0; i < listInt.size(); i++) {
            System.out.print(" " + listInt.get(i).toInteger());
        }
```

output:

```
70 35 81 8 96 64 46 57 99 19
```

file content:

```
70 35 81 8 96 64 46 57 99 19
```

Comment: Why `Integer.parseInt(token)`? Wouldn't simple `nextInt` do the trick? We can prevent it from making mistakes by using `hasNextInt`, there is no try-catch block needed (OP claims that file contains only integers so even `hasNext` should be safe).

Comment: no because the return type is int .http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt()

Comment: That is the point. In `Integer.parseInt(in.next())` can be replaced with `nextInt()` (if you need `Integer` instead of `int` you can let autobixing handle it).

Comment: @Pshemo I saw that the op uses the wrapper calss for int  so IntegerType is an object like Integer type

Comment: Thanks Pshemo and Kick Buttowski for your help. I'll have to mess around with it for a while.

Comment: @user3267939 I did not see you have wrapper class IngeterType, so I updated my answer. plz lemee know if it helps or not :)